# sed command replace with regex

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have been bashing my head against the wall trying to get sed to search a file are replace a timestamp.

example replace strings (file):

```
<script src="<@ofbizContentUrl>/xxx/js/v6/jsfile.js?v=201711271300</@ofbizContentUrl>"></script>

<script src="<@ofbizContentUrl>/xxx/js/v6/jsfile2.js?v=20171127245</@ofbizContentUrl>"></script>
```

basically I want to replace the 201711271300 in the examples with the current timestamp which i have saved in a variable date. The dates in the example differ from case to case.

I've been trying

```
sudo sed -i "s/?v=.+?(?=<)/?v=${date}/g" file
```

to no avail, going on 2 hours now

Comment: You can do this with less headache with python in couple of lines. Do you have to use `ancient sed`?

Comment: `sed` doesn't support lookahead regex

Comment: i guess i dont basically we have a shell script that deploys our nee builds of our website so i was trying to do it on the fly during the build process but i guess i can just add a python command in the sh script that will handle the replacement

Comment: @anubhava uhg thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
sed "s/?v=\([0-9]*<\)/?v=${date}</g" $file
```

It uses a simpler pattern: all digits until you hit a `<`. Replace by a data (and restore the `<`).